# get http request every 60 second Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

I need to get http request every 60 second from

```
 list(von: number, bis: number) BehaviorSubject<Termin[]> {
   const url = this.terminBauen()
   this.http.get<Termin[]>(url).subscribe({
      termine => {
        this.termine.next(termine);
       }     
     });
 }
```

Comment: create an Observable using `Rx.Observable.interval` or `Rx.Observable.timer` like `Rx.Observable.interval(60000)` and then subscribe on that to call your http get method. The Observable will emit after every 60 sec and the http call will be made.

Comment: Rx.Observable.interval(60000).subscribe( this.http.get<Termin[]>(url) => {this.termine.next(termine) });  like this?

Comment: yes like that.. does it work for you?

Comment: Nope, I get compile failed.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Can you try like this ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6-oyavdx?file=src/app/app.component.ts